# Asking about Group By and sorting in Mysqli query

Tags: mysqli

First of all, i apologize if there are similar posts in this forum, please help me master, i need a efficient way for querying summary of my visitor table, i have table similiar like this :
Table name : table_visitor

```
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+
| id |    city    | country |     time_visit      |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | london     | uk      | 2017-11-02 13:01:00 |
|  2 | new york   | usa     | 2017-11-13 00:23:00 |
|  3 | london     | uk      | 2017-11-17 10:23:00 |
|  4 | bristol    | uk      | 2017-11-22 07:00:00 |
|  5 | texas      | usa     | 2017-11-30 04:10:00 |
|  6 | dublin     | ireland | 2017-12-02 13:01:00 |
|  7 | new york   | usa     | 2017-12-13 00:23:00 |
|  8 | london     | uk      | 2017-12-17 10:23:00 |
|  9 | bristol    | uk      | 2017-12-22 07:00:00 |
| 10 | london     | uk      | 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 11 | washington | usa     | 2018-01-13 14:00:00 |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+
```

I need efficient query that has shortest time to execute that can result separate data (group, count and sort by alphabeth the city and country column by sorting from time_visit column) like example table shown below.
Table name : visitor_summary

```
+----+------+-------+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | year | month |                    city                    |         country         |
+----+------+-------+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2017 |    11 | london(2),bristol(1),new york(1),texas(1)  | uk(3),usa(2)            |
|  2 | 2017 |    12 | bristol(1),dublin(1),london(1),new york(1) | uk(2),ireland(1),usa(1) |
|  3 | 2018 |     2 | london(1),washington(1)                    | uk(1),usa(1)            |
+----+------+-------+--------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky reporting problem.  The `GROUP_CONCAT` function can do what you want, but that would require already having a table with the cities and their total counts, per month and year, or the countries and their total counts.  So, one approach is to do a rollup, first aggregating by year, month and city/country, and then aggregating again by only year and month, to obtain the CSV report you want.

```
SELECT
    t1.year,
    t1.month,
    t1.cities,
    t2.countries
FROM
(
    SELECT
        year,
        month,
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.city_label, '(', CAST(t.cnt AS CHAR(50)), ')') cities
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            YEAR(time_visit) year,
            MONTH(time_visit) month,
            CONCAT(country, '-', city) AS city_label,
            COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM table_visitor
        GROUP BY YEAR(time_visit), MONTH(time_visit), CONCAT(country, '-', city)
    ) t
    GROUP BY year, month
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        year,
        month,
        GROUP_CONCAT(t.country, '(', CAST(t.cnt AS CHAR(50)), ')') countries
    FROM
    (
        SELECT YEAR(time_visit) year, MONTH(time_visit) month, country, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM table_visitor
        GROUP BY YEAR(time_visit), MONTH(time_visit), country
    ) t
    GROUP BY
        year, month
) t2
    ON t1.year = t2.year AND t1.month = t2.month
GROUP BY
    t1.year,
    t1.month;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that in my output I refer to cities using both the city and country name.  The reason for this is a given city name may not be unique across countries.  For example, the US state of Ohio has a city called London, so just using London in the report might be ambiguous.

If you want to order the CSV data in either the city or country columns, then look into using `ORDER BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

**Edit:**

From your comments below, it appears that you may have a really large table, and furthermore, that you might need to run this report often in production.  I would suggest that you break down the report into pieces.  For example, you could run a proc which uses the above query at the end of each year/month.  Then, it could insert a record for the result into your suggested `visitor_summary` table.  This way, production would not be impacted by having to crunch the entire historical table all at once.

Comment: I think since the beginning I designed the database incorrectly, I will try to rebuild the database like your suggestion. I'll let you know about the update as soon as possible. once again, thank you master.

Comment: @FalianAridua I didn't rebuild your database, I only gave you a query to generate the output you want.  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I thought I had wrongly designed the database from the start, at first i never thought of adding a table called 'visitor_summary' as i demonstrated above, because now that there are lots of data in the 'visitor' table, it would be better if i made a visitor summary for my website, I'm afraid that in the future the size of the database will increase greatly if I don't summarize the 'visitor' data. For a while, i think i will input visitor info in both the 'visitor' table and 'visitor_summary' table. I will learn the code that you provided. thank you sir.

Comment: I think the `visitor_summary` table should not even be a table at all.  It is just data derived from `table_visitor`.  I recommend maybe taking my query using it as a view.  Getting my answer to run fast is another story, and maybe could be the topic of your next question.

Comment: I am worried that it will overload the server if it displays the results of the queries that you provide & i think it will take a long time to execute if there 100,000+ data. I'm curious, which one is faster, the query you are provide or if i insert data directly in both the 'visitor' & 'visitor_summary' tables, for example in the 'visitor' table i will insert london>uk> 2017-11-02 13:00:00 and in the 'visitor_summary' table i will insert 2017>11>-uk-london>uk(1) ?? FYI website can reach around 500 visits per day, now the data is almost 80,000 in only 'visitor' table since the last update :(

Comment: 'I would suggest that you break down the report into pieces. For example, you could run a proc which uses the above query at the end of each year/month." Correct sir, that's exactly what I will do for a while. You have given a good answer, I really appreciate your advice and kindness, forgive me for troubling you sir. :)